# Is there a way to specify the text shown in the tooltip?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tooltip

[image]I want to be able to specify what's shown in the tooltip, the default is that it shows x and y, but is there a way i can change this to whatever i want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpldatacursor import datacursor

x1, y1 = np.random.random((2, 5))
x2, y2 = np.random.random((2, 5))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x1, y1, 'ro')
ax.plot(x2, y2, 'bo')

datacursor()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to see in the tooltip? I've added an answer that should allow you to add desired text for the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

The `datacursor` function accepts a `formatter` arg that allows one to specify the label format. The label for each plot can be specified first and then formatted(rendered)  in the datacursor. In the example code below, the tooltip will show the text `x1,y1(or x2,y2) values`, whenever the cursor is clicked on their respective co-ordinate points.

```
ax.plot(x1, y1, 'ro', label='x1, y1 values')
ax.plot(x2, y2, 'bo', label='x2, y2 values')

datacursor(formatter='{label}'.format)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want, for example, rename x and y into foo and bar,
you can use

```
datacursor(formatter="foo: {x:06.4f}\nbar: {y:06.4f}".format)
```

[image]